# Is it possible to get hot chocolate using an espresso machine?

Tags: espresso-machine

I was wondering if it's possible to brew hot chocolate using ground cocoa beans on the espresso machine as if it was coffee. Has anyone tried something like this? I've seen some people on the internet doing it with powder cocoa but it doesn't seem safe.

Answer (score 3):

The steam wand will do a terrific job of mixing, heating, and fluffing (what's the technical term?) milk + cocoa powder into killer hot chocolate.

Personally I recommend unsweetened cocoa powder, but most people probably want a sugary drink.

But I don't think you'll want to use the main espresso part of the machine.

Comment: The shop I used to work it would make chocolate milk using whole milk and Ghirardelli unsweeted ground cocoa and then steam it. Best hot chocolate I have ever had.